# Using excel to count complete/incomplete across several sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to do the following.

I have 10 sheets labeled Teacher1 through Teacher 10 and an 11th sheet named StudentRoster.

In the StudentRoster sheet I have a list of 100 students names.  StudentA, StudentB, StudentC, etc..

In each of the sheets Teacher1, Teacher2, Teacher3, etc. I have about 20 cells in column A that use some of the names listed within StudentRoster (these would be class rosters)

In each of the Teacher1, Teacher2, etc sheets column A will have the student names and column B will be a column in which I will manually insert an "X" to indicate completion of an assignment.  Within the StudentRoster sheet I would like to have excel search through Teacher1, Teacher2, Teacher3, ... Teacher10 and count how many "X"s exist for StudentA.  **Student A may or many not be in all Teacher sheets**

Can someone provide me with a way of doing this, I have been trying to use the COUNTIFS formula but I am struggling having it look for StudentA and then to begin counting only the "X"s for StudentA.

Comment: SO isn't here to just *"provide"* you with code. Give a [mcve]. If you're just using regular Excel formulas I don't think that counts as programming within the topic of this site, see the [help].

Comment: I would say that Excel formulas are on topic. They are certainly a very common question. However, the first part of the above comment is absolutely correct. If you want help with debugging what you have written you need to include your best attempt above. Showing some sample data and expected result also goes a long way to helping elicit useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List your worksheets on the 11th sheet and name the range `sheets` then you can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!A:A"),A1,INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!B:B"),"X"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to add a column to each teacher sheet to the left of the studentname. In that column you put in =COUNTIF(range;"X"). Fill in relevant range e.g. C1:K1.
In the student roster list you could use add a top row with the teacher names and sum. With sumif(range of student names in Teacher 1 sheet; select cell with student name in roster; range in teacher 1 sheet with countif outcomes)
Then sum over all sumif statements by student for the total.

There would be other methods, but this one is least complicated and straightforward I think.